# How to implement IF NOT TRUE

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

**Situation:**


The following script will check the column N for data, if any cell starting from row 3 in column N have data, the script will extract the data and sent me it by email.

But if any cell starting from ROW3 in column N did't have data, in the email body show by said "Dear Team, any problem for the moment"

How can I do that? I try to use if not, but I thinks is not the correct way to do that.

My Script is the following:

```
function emailv1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Support = ss.getSheetByName("Shift");
  var lastrow = Support.getLastRow();

  var data1 = Support.getRange(3, 1, lastrow).getValues(); // XML ID
  var data2 = Support.getRange(3, 2, lastrow).getValues(); // SEQ NAME
  var data3 = Support.getRange(3, 14, lastrow).getValues(); // Notes
  var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Funtion Date + Format

  //var name = Browser.inputBox('Monitor', 'Ingrese el Horario Monitoreado', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

/////////////////////// FOLLOWUP TABLE /////////////////////////
  var report = " "
  var supportTable ="";
  for(var i in data3)
  {
     if(data3[i]!="") 

      { supportTable += "<tr><td style='color:blue;padding:5px'>" + data1[i]
                                      + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data2[i] 
                                      + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data3[i] 
                                      + "</td></tr>";


  report ="Dears: <br><br><b>The following sequences were reported with faults:</b><br><br><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'border = 1 cellpadding = 5; align='center'><tr><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>XML ID</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>SEQUENCER</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Notes</tr>" + supportTable + "</table>";
      }
  }   

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// URL SHIFT ////////////////////////////
  var report4 = "<br><H1 align='center'><a href=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXX>URL SHIFT</a></H1>"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  MailApp.sendEmail("XXXX@gmail.com",
                    "[CUSTOMER NAME] Shift Change - " + date2, 
                    report,
                    {name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
                    htmlBody: report +'<br><br><br><br>'+ report4});


  Support.getRange('N3:N133').clearContent(); // I want to put all cell in column N but I don't know what but for that razon I put a range.

}
```

I will appreciate any help, I try the followig

```
else if(data3[i]="") {report="text"]; //not working
else if(data3[i]=="") {report="text"]; //not working
else if(data3[i]==="") {report="text"]; //not working
```

Comment: How about just `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems you want to add a new functionality to the code. Where in when column N is empty you get an email with a text "Dear Team, any problem for the moment" (not sure what that means, though!).

I modified the code to cehck if you have any data in supportTable like so:

```
if (supportTable == ""){
   report = "Dear Team, any problem for the moment" 
  } else {

    report ="Dears: <br><br><b>The following sequences were reported with faults:</b><br><br><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'border = 1 cellpadding = 5; align='center'><tr><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>XML ID</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>SEQUENCER</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Notes</tr>" + supportTable + "</table>";
  }
```

You can even use isEmpty(str) by @AlGoreRythm here instead if you like. And if there is no data in that variable set the body of the email to the above-mentioned string. **EDIT: Something I missed earlier was getValues gives a 2D array of data, to access the data you have to use two indices and not one like previously (Ex: data[i][0] and not data[i])**

```
 function emailv1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Support = ss.getSheetByName("Shift");
  var lastrow = Support.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("LastRow: "+lastrow)
  var data1 = Support.getRange(3, 1, lastrow-2).getValues(); // XML ID
  var data2 = Support.getRange(3, 2, lastrow-2).getValues(); // SEQ NAME
  var data3 = Support.getRange(3, 14, lastrow-2).getValues(); // Notes
  var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-3", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"); // Funtion Date + Format

  //var name = Browser.inputBox('Monitor', 'Ingrese el Horario Monitoreado', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

/////////////////////// FOLLOWUP TABLE /////////////////////////
  var report = " "
  var supportTable ="";

  for(var i in data3)
  {  


     if(data3[i][0]!="") 

      { supportTable += "<tr><td style='color:blue;padding:5px'>" + data1[i][0]
                                      + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data2[i][0]
                                      + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data3[i][0] 
                                      + "</td></tr>";



      }
    else {

      Logger.log("Empty Row: " + i) 
    }
  }   

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// URL SHIFT ////////////////////////////
  // Check to see if supoortTable has any data in it, if not set the text to "Dear Team, any problem for the moment" 
  if (supportTable == ""){
   report = "Dear Team, any problem for the moment" 
  } else {

    report ="Dears: <br><br><b>The following sequences were reported with faults:</b><br><br><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'border = 1 cellpadding = 5; align='center'><tr><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>XML ID</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>SEQUENCER</th><th style='background-color:black;color:white'>Notes</tr>" + supportTable + "</table>";
  }
var report4 = "<br><H1 align='center'><a href=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXX>URL SHIFT</a></H1>"
Logger.log(report)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  MailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@gmail.com",
                    "[CUSTOMER NAME] Shift Change - " + date2, 
                    report,
                    {name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
                    htmlBody: report +'<br><br><br><br>'+ report4});


  Support.getRange('N3:N133').clearContent(); // I want to put all cell in column N but I don't know what but for that razon I put a range.

}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but still did't work... send an email in blank... maybe the problema is in the row 2 all column have data... I don't know any way thanks for your time

Comment: This script never looks at row 2. This starts taking the data from row3

Comment: Jogannathan Alagurajan Here you have the spreadsheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfZ1zQ5lokrC0DN6FMgMCmM5WCCBL9trHxpJlN-aRiY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @LADServiceDesk Ok modified the code, should work :). I tried it with sheet you sent across, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could have this function

```
function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

which will check if any string is empty. If your string has `" "` then this would fail. If you need to check if the string is empty OR contains no white space, you could do this:

```
function isEmptyBrute(str) {
    str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

Which you can then just simply do this:

```
//if it's empty it will return true
if(isEmpty(data3[i])) ...
```

working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dL0h93ew/

Comment: Hi is not working, the i put the first script on top and add if(isEmpty(data3[i])) report = "textxxxxx"; is not working sent me an email in blank only appear report 4.... The script should be if the any cell in column N is not empty create a table and show the information but if all cell in column N are empty in that case report = "textxxxx"; and the email in the body should be apprear textxxxx

Comment: Whoa what? I was looking at your `if/else` statements, which you were checking to see if a value is empty. And you seemed confused how to check `if not empty` so I decided to help you by making a function that checks to see if the value you provide is empty then return true. So you wouldn't need a `if not true` thing. I've added in the jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Why the email the body is in blank... If you prefer I can shared a example spreadsheet

Comment: Ohh... yes you show me but I am trying to integrate to my script and I don't know why is not working as spect.

Comment: Thanks but is not working... The script create a table if the cell are not empty, but if empty the script show be email me with a text that part is not working... I don't know why

Comment: Sorry, but your english is too far off. Don't really understand anything you're saying. I looked at your code and made it easier for you to check to see if a value is empty. If it's not working for you, maybe you did not include the relevant code to ask in your question.  You just posted your entire code and I don't feel like digging into it, that's your job (no offense). You should clearly state your problem, and what you've tried so people understand what you're asking better.

Comment: Certainly you are correct, already modify my query in the body of the incident if you can check it for the last time and see if you can help me I will appreciate ---- thanks.

Comment: Yes, I see your problem ` if(data3[i]!="") ` you're `assigning` here. If you need to check if it's empty then you need to use my method and pass `data3[i]` as parameter like shown. For even more added security, you can use `data3[i].toString()`. Without any kind of sample data or anything else to go off of, I don't know how I can help you any more.